# EC2 persistent instance retirement scheduled

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

On the personal health dashboard in the AWS Console, I've got this notification

> EC2 persistent instance retirement scheduled

yesterday which says that one of my ec2 instances is scheduled to retire on 13th March 2019. The status was 'upcoming' while the start and end times both were set to 14-Mar-2019.

The content of the notification starts with:

> Hello,
>   EC2 has detected degradation of the underlying hardware hosting your Amazon EC2 instance (instance-ID: i-xxxxxxxxxx) associated with your AWS account (AWS Account ID: xxxxxxxxxx) in the xxxx region. Due to this degradation your instance could already be unreachable. We will stop your instance after 2019-03-13 00:00 UTC.
>   ....

I've got yet another notification today for the same instance and with the same subject line but the status has been changed to 'ongoing' and the start time is 27-Feb-2019 while the end time is 14-Mar-2019.

I was planning to do a start-stop of the instance next week but does the second notification tell me to do is ASAP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is better to do stop/start ASAP. Even in your message it says:

> Due to this degradation your instance could already be unreachable